# The area between the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the function $y=\log(x)$

Tags: calculus

How do you solve $x^2 + (\log x)^2=1$ to find the $x$ coordinate of the intercept (other than $x=1$)?

Comment: I don't see how you can analytically find the other solution. It's also not totally clear what "between" means here when $x \leq 0$. Nor is it clear whether $\log(x)$ is meant to be the upper limit or the lower limit. This is all around a badly worded question.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-First of all the "other" solution is $x\approx 0.3999$. Then you have to calculate the integral
$$\int_{0.3999}^1(\log(x)-(-\sqrt{1-x^2})dx=\left[\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}+2\log(x)+\arcsin(x)\right]_{0.3999}^1=\quad .....$$

Comment: Thanks so much. How did you get 0.399?

Comment: It won't be .399.  By looking at an online grapher for -(1+x^2)^.5 vs log(x) and then messing around in excel until the numbers got real close, the first intercept will be close to .1012  I can't find or think of a way to solve this analytically.

Comment: @user714878: You can do it by several ways involved numerical methods or using a calculator. I have choosed by obvious reason a calculator (the plotter Desmos).

Comment: @user78090: Desmos and Wolfram (look at Yif an's answer above) against your calculation, I bet on $x\approx 0.3999$. Greetings.

Comment: I'm not seeing it.  Y=Log(x) with x=.399 gives -.399 so that's an x,y pair of .399,-.399.  If I plug that into the circle equation x^2+y^2=1, I get .318=1 so that point isn't on the circle.  Y=log(x) with x=.1012 gives -.9948.  If I plug in the x,y pair of .1012,-.9948 to x^2+y^2=1, I get .9999=1 so that point is about on the circle.  This also agrees visually with a graph of log(x) and a graph of sqrt(1-x^2) on Desmos.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't, because there is no analytical solution. The numerical solutions to $\log(x)^2=1-x^2$ are given by $x_0=1$ and $x_1 \approx 0.399891274286662\dots$ (from Wolfram Alpha). If you evaluate the integral, you will get
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_0}\log(x)-(-\sqrt{1-x^2})dx\approx0.16285301751535337207596620684631498008\dots.$$